# Suplement books for calculus course?

Tags: calculus, big-list, book-recommendation

I'm looking for books that could enhance the learning of calculus. At the moment, I have the following titles:

- [Counterexamples in Calculus;](http://www.maa.org/publications/ebooks/counterexamples-in-calculus)
- [Irresistible integrals;](http://ebooks.cambridge.org/ebook.jsf?bid=CBO9780511617041)
- [Inside calculus;](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387989323)
- [The Calculus Gallery;](http://press.princeton.edu/titles/7905.html)
- [Inside Interesting Integrals;](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1493912763)
- [The History of Calculus and It's Conceptual Development;](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486605094)
- [The Historical Development of Calculus;](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387943137)
- [Excursions in Calculus;](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0883853175)

Do you know more books that such as the examples I just gave?

Comment: Calculus: A Complete Course by Robert A. Adams offers a pretty good look at calculus in my opinion. I haven't read the entire thing, but the help I've had so far from it has been good. That's all I have to offer, I'm afraid!

Comment: A Primer of Infinitesimal Analysis, John Bell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Calculus book recommendations (for complete beginner)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/322892/calculus-book-recommendations-for-complete-beginner)

[What books are recommended for learning calculus on my own?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/614376/calculus-self-taught-books)

Those are good books you've stated; other books mentioned by others in the aforementioned links, like the classic Spivak, or even the newer Courant's Calculus books, should be enough for a great start to a Calculus course.

*Considering you want mainly supplements, the **Internet** is probably the best resource for you, followed by  Schaum's solved problems books in both Physics (Mainly **Electromagnetism** and **Mechanics** , and possibly even **QM**) and Math (I.e. **Schaum's 3000 solved problems in Calculus, Schaum's 3000 solved problems in Advanced Calculus** etc...)*

If you're not satisfied, then take a look here: http://math.about.com/od/booksresourcesdvds/tp/calculustp.htm